# Efficiency of various Ewald-type schemes for the summation of electrostatic interactions

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am looking into implementation of Ewald summation techniques for a number of point charges in periodic 3D space (i.e. a molecular simulation box with periodic boundary conditions). The “mainstream” Ewald-type techniques I know are:

- original Ewald scheme
- particle-mesh Ewald (PME)
- smooth particle-mesh Ewald (SPME)

However, while I can find papers describing each of those, I have not been able to find a comprehensive article/white paper/technique note comparing their implementations and their CPU timings on a typical dense system (liquid, protein in solvent, whatever…). What resources do you know of on this topic?

Comment: Why not give it a go and just benchmark it? I know DLPOLY Classic implements Ewald and SPME. Run some of their test ensembles with both and see how it behaves and scales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also unsuccessfully tried to look for such a paper in the past but below are some useful resources I've found. The only definitive answer I can give you is that traditional Ewald summation will be slower than a particle-mesh technique for any relevant system sizes (this is backed up in several of the references below).

Chapter 4.9 of the [GROMACS user manual](ftp://ftp.gromacs.org/pub/manual/manual-4.6.3.pdf) has some very nice discussion on their various implemenations of long-range electrostatics and appropriate references.

The [LAMMPS documentation](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/kspace_style.html) also has quite a few references and some bits of helpful discussion.

You can also try digging through the [AMBER manual](http://ambermd.org/doc11/Amber11.pdf) which uses a PME implementation but I haven't read any of this myself.

Also [here](http://codeblue.umich.edu/hoomd-blue/doc/classhoomd__script_1_1charge_1_1pppm.html) you can find implementation details for the PPPM method in HOOMD (helpful if you're interested in GPGPU implementations).

I think the most relevant bit of discussion is probably this excerpt in the GROMACS manual:

> The Particle-Particle Particle-Mesh methods of Hockney & Eastwood can
>   also be applied in GROMACS for the treatment of long range
>   electrostatic interactions [99]. Although the P3M method was the ﬁrst
>   efﬁcient long-range electrostatics method for molecular simulation,
>   the smooth PME (SPME) method has largely replaced P3M as the method of
>   choice in atomistic simulations. One performance disadvantage of the
>   original P3M method was that it required 3 3D-FFT back transforms to
>   obtain the forces on the particles. But this is not required for P3M
>   and the forces can be derived through analytical differentiation of
>   the potential, as done in PME. The resulting method is termed P3M-AD.
>   The only remaining difference between P3M-AD and PME is the
>   optimization of the lattice Green inﬂuence function for error
>   minimization that P3M uses. However, in 2012 it has been shown that
>   the SPME inﬂuence function can be modiﬁed to obtain P3M [100]. This
>   means that the advantage of error minimization in P3M-AD can be used
>   at the same computational cost and with the same code as PME, just by
>   adding a few lines to modify the inﬂuence function. However, at
>   optimal parameter setting the effect of error minimization in P3M-AD
>   is less than 10%. P3M-AD does show large accuracy gains with
>   interlaced (also known as staggered) grids, but that is not supported
>   in GROMACS (yet).

If you're really looking to dive in, you can look at the source code for these packages (I believe you need a license for AMBER) to see the actual implementations.